# Scala - Trying to wrap occurrences of booleans using implicits

Tags: scala, apache-spark, implicit

I'm new to implicits in scala and am sure there is a way to do this but have tried everything I can think of.

I have a trait:

```
trait WrappedDataframe[T] extends Rep[DataFrame]


 def apply[S](colName: String): Col[T] = {
    // Functionality to get our Col[T]
 }
```

This is Rep my base representation which also contains the function to use equality:

```
trait Rep[T] {
 def === (e2: Rep[T]): Rep[T] = Equality[T](this, e2)
}
```

For Col is a trait that extends Rep like so:

```
trait Col[T] extends Rep[T]
case class BaseCol[T](df: String, n: String) extends Col[T]
class CompCol[T](val lhs: Rep[T], val rhs: Rep[T]) extends Col[T] with Serializable
case class Equality[T](override val lhs: Rep[T], override val rhs: Rep[T]) extends CompCol[T](lhs, rhs)
```

and I've wrapped a DataFrame:

```
val wrappedIntDf = intDf.wrap()
```

So with this I can use similar syntax to spark to do comparisons on Reps. In my below examples h1 is working fine but h2 has the noted error.

```
val h1: Rep[DataFrame] = wrappedIntDf("users") === wrappedIntDf("users2")
val h2: Rep[DataFrame] = wrappedIntDf("users") === true // Type mismatch. Required: Rep[DataFrame], found: Boolean
```

Obviously this is because it is just a Boolean. But I really want to be able to use the above syntax so I looked into implicits and came up with:

```
implicit def booleanToRep(b: Boolean): Rep[DataFrame] = Literal(b)
case class Literal[DataFrame](bool: Boolean) extends Rep[DataFrame]
```

I've added this to the scope of my Rep trait above. Nothing changes in terms of my example that I want to work. Can anyone see what might be wrong with my approach?

Comment: Note that `Dataframe` in your `Literal` definition is hiding the actual `Dataframe` type. I'm even surprised the `implicit def` compiles.

Comment: Implicit conversion is often painful to troubleshoot for you and your users. Why not create another `===` method accepting a `Boolean`?

Comment: @GaëlJ the reason I don't want to create another ```===``` method accepting ```Boolean``` is because I intend to flesh out the solution to allow not just ```Boolean``` but ```String```, ```Integer``` and more literal types using T as type. First I want to solve this implicit issue for a base case (```Boolean```)

Comment: I understand but on the other hand it's almost the same amount of code to create the N implicit conversions. That would not be the case if you intend to have other operators than `===` later though.